# How to get a noisy density matrix after partial measurements in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, simulation, noise

I'm trying to study the effect of noise on a quantum system with partial measurements using Qiskit. Suppose I have $N + M$ qubits and I run a quantum circuit and measure $M$ of them. I want to know the quantum state on the remaining $N$ qubits *given the measurement outcomes on the $M$ qubits I measured*. In other words, I want to post-select (condition) on some measurement outcomes.

If I'm working with a noiseless circuit, I can do this by building my usual circuit and appending the instruction `circuit.snapshot(label = "psi", snapshot_type = "statevector")` after my measurements. Then, I can use the `AerSimulator` to simulate my circuit and get out the quantum state as a snapshot after any series of measurements using:

```
results = simulator.run(circuit, shots = shots, memory = True).result()
states = results.data()["snapshots"]["statevector"]["psi"]
```

But what happens if I want to implement noise in my simulator? I know how to do this using `AerSimulator`, but I'm not sure how to get the state I'm looking for.

One option is to use the instruction `circuit.snapshot(label = "rho", snapshot_type = "density_matrix")`. Is this the recommended way to do the simulation when I want to see the effect of noise after partially measuring a quantum system?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the simulator state using [simulator instructions](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/simulators/1_aer_provider.html#Custom-Simulator-Instructions) such as [`save_density_matrix`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.save_density_matrix.html). The table in the linked page shows what are the supported simulation methods for each instruction. So, you can pick a simulator that supports noisy simulation then choose one of the available instructions.

As an example, let's create a noise model and pass it to statevector simulator:

```
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider

provider = IBMProvider()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_manila')
noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend)

noisy_simulator = AerSimulator(method = 'statevector', noise_model = noise_model)
```

Now, we create a sample circuit of five qubits and measure two of them. We insert `save_density_matrix` instruction to save the state of the remaining qubits, and set `conditional` parameter to `True` to associate the state with the measurement result:

```
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit

circ = QuantumCircuit(5, 2)
circ.h(2)
circ.cx(2, 1)
circ.cx(1, 0)
circ.cx(2, 3)
circ.cx(3, 4)
circ.barrier()
circ.measure(0, 0)
circ.measure(1, 1)
circ.save_density_matrix(qubits=[2, 3, 4], label="rho", conditional=True)
circ.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

Now we run the experiment and display the state:

```
from IPython.display import display

job = noisy_simulator.run(circ)
result = job.result()

# Get statevector for each measurement:
for meas, state in result.data()['rho'].items():
    display(meas)
    display(state.draw('latex'))
```

The output should look like:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this fully captures my question, since the resulting object we get out is a statevector, not a density matrix. For example, just because we measure qubits 0 and 1 and collapse their state, the uncertainty in readout errors should mean there is a probability that we measured 0 when really it was a 1, and vice versa.

Comment: You are right. I think we need to set `pershot` to `True` to get the statevector for each shot. Any way, I updated my answer to use `save_density_matrix` instruction.

Comment: I think the key here is that you need to take multiple shots if you want the density matrix to become mixed (as it should with a noise model). What Qiskit returns seems to always be a pure state, and you need to average over the results to get the noisy density matrix.